# Errors importing BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to import BeautifulSoup4, but am running into importation issues.

I am running Python 2.7.9 as 32 bit Windows (MSC v.1500)

I attempted to install BeautifulSoup4 as both a tarball and using pip. Both attempts have "installed" bs4, but import bs4 yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 294, in <module>
    from . import _htmlparser
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_htmlparser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from HTMLParser import (
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\HTMLParser.py", line 47, in <module>
    """, re.VERBOSE)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

I have no idea how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is an error with your regex. Post it here!

Comment: How did you install? Like this`pip install beautifulsoup4`??

Comment: @MauroBaraldi Forgive my ignorance, but I am not sure what you mean by post my regex.

Comment: @sailesh Yes, that is how I installed using pip.

Comment: Could you post the part of the code that breaks?

Comment: The code breaks when I type import bs4

Comment: `pip install beautifulsoup4 --upgrade` try this and import again. Tell me if this doesn't work

Comment: I upgraded as you suggested. Now it works under the default python executable. However, I need to run the python executable that is including the folder C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2 (to work with GIS scripts in ArcGIS). I am still getting the error message when running the ArcGIS python executable. Is this because pip is only installing for the default python.exe? If this is the case, why is bs4 installing in the ArcGIS site-packages?

Comment: Interestingly, BeautifulSoup loads in python when called from within ArcGIS 10.2, but not when I run the python executable by itself. This may be more of a case of ArcGIS misbehaving.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: can you post the part of the script which uses the bs4 module?

Comment: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup ## yields error message. Then, when I type soup = BeautifulSoup(html), I receive the error "Beautiful Soup is not defined"

Comment: run this command and reply with the output: `pip freeze | grep -i "soup"`

Comment: I ran pip freeze | finstr /i "soup". The output was BeautifulSoup==3.2.1, beautifulsoup4==4.3.2. I uninstalled BeautifulSoup 3, but that didn't solve the issue.